# How to suppress javascript exception?

Tags: javascript, exception, suppress-warnings

In my application i am getting the content of some other domain's page. Along with the content it is running the javascript associated with the particular page. In the javascript code "document.selection.createRange()" is written which is throwing exception at run time in IE (since in IE due to security concern you can't change iframe's data or the reverse).

So my question is how to suppress the exception.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Removed my answer because the offending code lives in the external page and so can't be tried for exceptions.

Comment: So you're asking how, using a script, you can defeat the browser's security measures against scripting attacks?

Comment: I am not asking to defeat the browser's security, only i am asking how to suppress the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in jQuery by using a [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) with a page fragment.

> If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed

Be aware though that this will only work if the other domain allows your domain access via [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) http headers.